# Add a single backslash ("\") to string in python

Tags: python, replace

I have an array of strings which looks like:

```
["U0001f308", "U0001F602"]
```

I need to add “\” in front of the first letter U so the output will be like:

```
["\U0001f308", "\U0001F602"]
```

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
matches = ["U0001f308", "U0001F602"]
emojis = [emoji.replace('U', r"\U") for emoji in matches]
print(emojis) #this prints ['\\U0001f308', '\\U0001F602'] which has two blacklashes
```

How can i add only one backslash in front of every string?

Comment: It does have only one backslash. When you print a list it calls `repr` on its members which prints the backslash as a double backslash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \_\_str\_\_ and \_\_repr\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr)

Comment: It looks like you're actually trying to create a single unicode character, not a string with the characters backslash, 'U', '0', etc. Is this correct?

Comment: I tried to use chr(92) and merge it into the array but it prints double \\.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly print list of unicode characters in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263783/how-to-properly-print-list-of-unicode-characters-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you want is the following code:

```py
matches = ["U0001f308", "U0001F602"]
emojis = [emoji.replace('U', r"\U").encode().decode('unicode-escape') for emoji in matches]
print(emojis)
```

which prints

```
['', '']
```

It's the same result as when we execute the following code:

```py
print(["\U0001f308", "\U0001F602"])
```